# Rails : all fields in form are not saving in rails db instead few fields showing nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

View:

```
  <p>
    <%= form.label :FirstName %>
    <%= form.text_field :FirstName %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :LastName %>
    <%= form.text_field :LastName %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <%= form.label :PhoneNo %>
    <%= form.text_field :PhoneNo %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :Lane1 %>
    <%= form.text_field :Lane1 %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :Lane2 %>
    <%= form.text_field :Lane2 %> <br>
    <%= form.label :ZipCode %>
    <%= form.text_field :zipcode %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :State %>

    <%= form.select(:State, options_for_select([['Alaska','AK'],['Alabama','AL'], ['Arkansas','AR'],['Arizona','AZ'],['California','CA'],['Colorado','CO'],['Connecticut','CT'],['District of Columbia','DC'],['Delaware','DE'],['Florida','FL'],['Georgia','GA'],['Hawaii','HI'],['Iowa','IA'],['Idaho','ID'],['Illinois','IL'],['Indiana','IN'],['Kansas','KS'],['Kentucky','KY'],['Louisiana','LA'],['Massachusetts','MA'],['Maryland','MD'],['Maine','ME'],['Michigan','MI'],['Minnesota','MN'],['Missouri','MO'],['Mississippi','MS'],['Montana','MT'],['North Carolina','NC'],['North Dakota','ND'],['Nebraska','NE'],['New Hampshire','NH'],['New Jersey','NJ'],['New Mexico','NM'],['Nevada','NV'],['New York','NY'],['Ohio','OH'],['Oklahoma','OK'],['Oregon','OR'],['Pennsylvania','PA'],['Rhode Island','RI'],['South Carolina','SC'],['South Dakota','SD'],['Tennessee','TN'],['Texas','TX'],['Utah','UT'],['Virginia','VA'],['Vermont','VT'],['Washington','WA'],['Wisconsin','WI'],['West Virginia','WV'],['Wyoming','WY']])) %>

    <%= form.label :County %>
    <%= form.text_field :County %> 
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

(Line1 , line2, zipcode and country are not saving)

Controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @customers = Customer.all
    end

    def show
       @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new 
    end

    def create
        @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
         @customer.save
        redirect_to @customer
    end

    private 
        def customer_params
            params.require(:customer).permit(
               :FirstName, :LastName, :PhoneNo, :Line1, :Line2, :ZipCode, :State, :Country)
        end
    end
```

//sjhfkljifeui;eisdhABCNFJWHEkywqoka;cns,M bhwdgshcwlnq

Comment: Is that your actual code? You seem to have a lot of naming errors (e.g., `Lane1`, `:zipcode`, `:ZipCode`, etc.).

Comment: Is your form inside of a form_for or a form_with?

Comment: Your params hash keys MUST match the attribute names in your DB

Comment: Thanks @jvillian .

Comment: inside form_with. and now its working . @hashrocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your customer_params method , you permitted **:Line1, :Line2, :ZipCode**
but in your view it is **:Lane1, :Lane2, :zipcode** So it is not accepting them.You can fix it with two types.

1. Use the same names.
2. You can fix this(refer only if you want to accept all attributes)(**dirty way**)

   def customer_params

   ```
      params.require(:customer).permit!
   ```

   end

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p>
    <%= form.label :FirstName %>
    <%= form.text_field :FirstName %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :LastName %>
    <%= form.text_field :LastName %>
  </p>
  <br>
  <%= form.label :PhoneNo %>
    <%= form.text_field :PhoneNo %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :Line1 %>
    <%= form.text_field :Line1 %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :Line2 %>
    <%= form.text_field :Line2 %> <br>
    <%= form.label :ZipCode %>
    <%= form.text_field :ZipCode %> &nbsp
    <%= form.label :State %>

    <%= form.select(:State, options_for_select([['Alaska','AK'],['Alabama','AL'], ['Arkansas','AR'],['Arizona','AZ'],['California','CA'],['Colorado','CO'],['Connecticut','CT'],['District of Columbia','DC'],['Delaware','DE'],['Florida','FL'],['Georgia','GA'],['Hawaii','HI'],['Iowa','IA'],['Idaho','ID'],['Illinois','IL'],['Indiana','IN'],['Kansas','KS'],['Kentucky','KY'],['Louisiana','LA'],['Massachusetts','MA'],['Maryland','MD'],['Maine','ME'],['Michigan','MI'],['Minnesota','MN'],['Missouri','MO'],['Mississippi','MS'],['Montana','MT'],['North Carolina','NC'],['North Dakota','ND'],['Nebraska','NE'],['New Hampshire','NH'],['New Jersey','NJ'],['New Mexico','NM'],['Nevada','NV'],['New York','NY'],['Ohio','OH'],['Oklahoma','OK'],['Oregon','OR'],['Pennsylvania','PA'],['Rhode Island','RI'],['South Carolina','SC'],['South Dakota','SD'],['Tennessee','TN'],['Texas','TX'],['Utah','UT'],['Virginia','VA'],['Vermont','VT'],['Washington','WA'],['Wisconsin','WI'],['West Virginia','WV'],['Wyoming','WY']])) %>

    <%= form.label :County %>
    <%= form.text_field :County %> 
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
```